# field 'Name' can not be sorted in a query call error in only one environment. What can be the issue?

Tags: apex, soql

I have an object A which has a lookup to Contact. I am doing a SOQL in an Apex class and it looks like this:

`SELECT Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name FROM A__c ORDER BY Contact__r.Name`

This SOQL query is working fine in my dev sandbox but when I am trying to deploy it using changeset to staging sandbox, validation fails with an error - **field 'Name' can not be sorted in a query call**

I have checked whether the field is encrypted in staging sandbox and it is not. I can obviously change the code to not order by this field but that would not solve the real problem. Maybe the two sandboxes are not in sync and we need to find out what is not in sync.

What are the other causes of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here. Platform Encryption is enabled in staging sandbox and Contact.Name is field is setup for encryption. When I checked for encryption earlier, I only checked it on the Field detail page which does not show if the field is encrypted using Platform Encryption.